# A Meal fit for a King

Tags: riddle, humor

The riddle below describes a (semi) historical figure's culinary preferences.

Who is he and what is he eating?

---

> Far down below in the sea so blue;
>   Fries up your food, and boils it too;
>   Known as a ‘chip’ in the ‘land of the free’;
>   When the bet is equal, also flat as can be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> Good King Wenceslaus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wenceslaus_I,_Duke_of_Bohemia

he is eating

> Pizza

and his preference is for it to be

> Deep pan, crisp and even (mishearing of [deep and crisp and even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_King_Wenceslas), a line from the popular christmal carol, Good King Wenceslas)

This fits the riddle:

Fair down below in the see so blue

> Deep

Fries up your food, and boils it too;

> Pan

Known as a ‘chip’ in the ‘land of the free’

> Crisp (UK name for US 'chip')

When the bet is equal, also flat as can be.

> Even (50:50 odds are Evens, flat is also Even

Comment: Well done :) quicker than I expected as well. I wasn't sure how well known the original joke was, so tried not to make the lines of the riddle too oblique... I'll try for something harder next time!

Comment: Thanks for a good puzzle - regarding difficulty, it is worth reading this: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2947/the-many-eyes-effect

Comment: Ah thanks for the link, makes a lot of sense. Hadn't considered that and will bear it in mind :)

Comment: ok, i get the culinary preference, but how did you get the who?

Comment: He’s the titular figure referred to by the answer: see the last line of the first verse of [this song](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_King_Wenceslas), @SteveV

Comment: @SteveV there's an old Christmas cracker joke - How does Good King Wenceslas like his pizza? Deep pan, crisp, and even... Based on the carol.